# Rails, getting information from html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

In my rails app, I have **product** and **order** models. Lets say the products controller look like this:

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
  @order = Order.new
end
```

I have listed all products in the index view as divs. I would like to assign a product's id to the order *(@order.product_id = product.id)* when I click on its div.

```
= @products.each do |product|
 .product
   = product.name
   = product.price
```

Any ideas how to do this :? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger another request that includes the product ID, and land on a new action that assigns the ID to `@order.product_id`. In this case, it makes no sense to have `@order = Order.new` in your `products#index` action; instead you probably want a nested resource for orders within products, and a new controller for handling orders for a product.

#### config/routes.rb

```
resources :products do
  resources :orders
end
```

#### app/controllers/products_controller

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
end
```

Now, the `products#index` view can link to the nested route for a new order within a product. This will product a URL like `/products/123/orders/new`:

#### app/views/products/index.html.shaml

```
= @products.each do |product|
 .product
   = link_to new_product_order_path(product) do
     = product.name
     = product.price
```

Finally, you can render the new Order form using the product specified in the route:

#### app/controllers/orders_controller

```
def new
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @order = @product.orders.new
end
```